# Structural Equation Modelling - calculate modification indices with a categorical endogenous variable

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am trying to calculate modification indices in a Structural Equation Model (SEM) with an endogenous categorical variable. I am using the R package 'lavaan'. Running what it seems to be the correct code and I can not compute them. Reproducible example below.

Am I missing something?

## CODE

```
table.7.5 <-read.table("http://www.da.ugent.be/datasets/Agresti2002.Table.7.5.dat",header=TRUE)

table.7.5$mental <- ordered(table.7.5$mental,levels = c("well","mild","moderate","impaired"))

model <- "mental ~ ses + life"

fit <- sem(model, data=table.7.5)

summary(fit,rsq=TRUE,standardized=T,modindices=TRUE)
```

## Output

```
lavaan (0.5-22) converged normally after   4 iterations

  Number of observations                            40

  Estimator                                       DWLS      Robust
  Minimum Function Test Statistic                0.000       0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0           0
  Scaling correction factor                                     NA
  Shift parameter                                     
    for simple second-order correction (Mplus variant)

Parameter Estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                           Robust.sem

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  mental ~                                                              
    ses              -0.683    0.393   -1.739    0.082   -0.683   -0.296
    life              0.195    0.069    2.849    0.004    0.195    0.459

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .mental            0.000                               0.000    0.000

Thresholds:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    mental|t1        -0.161    0.375   -0.429    0.668   -0.161   -0.138
    mental|t2         0.746    0.382    1.954    0.051    0.746    0.640
    mental|t3         1.339    0.424    3.162    0.002    1.339    1.150

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .mental            1.000                               1.000    0.737

Scales y*:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    mental            1.000                               1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    mental            0.263

Modification Indices:

[1] lhs       op        rhs       mi        mi.scaled epc       sepc.lv   sepc.all  sepc.nox 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think about SEMs like this: You start with a null model, which has a bunch of degrees of freedom. Every time you estimate a parameter, you 'spend' a degree of freedom. The fewer degrees of freedom you spend (everything else being equal) the better.  Every time you spend a degree of freedom, your chi-square will go down. Modification indices tell you which parameters to free - but you've freed all the parameters already, so there are no modification indices.

Your model has zero degrees of freedom. You've spent all of the degrees of freedom, and your df and chi-square are zero. Your chi-square can't go down any more, and you can't spend any more df (you've got none left). Another way to say this is that your model is saturated.

This model is a regression model - you could have obtained the same result doing ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to fit a new model containing only "mental~life" and the model still has 0 degrees of freedom and no modindices available. Does this mean that the model with fewer variables also consumed all degrees of freedom?

Comment: Yes. If you want a toy example, just to make it work, add: "ses ~~ 0 * life" to your model. That will give you a df, a positive chi-square and a modification index.